# Cannot open emulator in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am using the android studio. I cannot open the emulator from the emulator. When I run the emulator it comes out the error:

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Pixel_API_27], use -list-avds to see valid list.
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

- control if you activated virtualization from bios
- if you have amd processor you need to follow some steps to use it with full compability, check for that from YouTube.

If you already did those steps, just uninstall all about avd and install them again.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Before that still can use, today suddenly come out the error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't installed the AVD correctly.

You will see the valid list with:

```
-list-avds
```

Or you can install AVDs at Tools > AVD Manager.